# How do I set a different username and password for each of the several databases I have in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: php

I successfully used a username and password to connect to the first database I created in PHPMyAdmin using a PHP script with mysqli. I am using PHPMyAdmin through GoDaddy. Now I created a second database, but the same username and password do not work when I tried to connect to it. How can I set a new username and password for this second database?

When I click on my database, the only option categories I see along the top are: Structure, SQL, Search, Query, Export, Import, Operations, Routines, Events, and Triggers. None of these seems offer a way to set/change the username/password.

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` comes with a [user manual](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/docs/) written in many languages

Comment: localhost or web hosting because on web hosting for example I have option "User management" and you could be on waaaay different platform? Please specify your question and try to see it from our point of view so we understand what are you asking for.

Comment: btw I am not going to vote down your question but unless you edit it explaining where exactly is this phpmyadmin people will!!! not that you have respect to lose but still.

Answer (score 0):

Example on how can I add users to my databases on my web hosting through Plesk Onyx 17.0.17 [image: example]

so your situation could be way different than mine or anyone else's reading the question.

Answer (score 0):

Choose your database. Then You just go to Privileges tab and click "Add user" under "New". From there you set user name,password, host and grand privileges fir this specific database. Just click "grant all privileges on database" 'nameofdatabe'.

Hope that helps.